# Image upload CURL command to PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, image-upload

I am pretty new to PHP CURL and was trying to call an API to do image upload (multiple files at a time). API documentation has given the below example in CURL. I have tested and it is working.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 123456789" -i -X POST -F "whitespace=1" \
 -F "imageData[]=@/path/to/images/milk.jpg" \
 -F "imageData[]=@/path/to/images/peas.jpg" \
 https://mytestapi.com/1.0/uploadimages
```

Now I need to convert it to PHP Curl. For some reason, I am always getting error "imageData" param invalid. Can someone please help

```
$token = '123456789';
$imgUrl = 'https://mytestapi.com/1.0/uploadimages';


$data_to_post = array();
$data_to_post['whitespace'] = '1';
$data_to_post['imageData[]'] = '@/path/to/images/milk.jpg';
$data_to_post['imageData[]'] = '@/path/to/images/peas.jpg';


$curl = curl_init($imgUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer '.$token]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_to_post);
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
$responseCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: whom will you give bounty

Comment: Thanks for bounty. You can upvote if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself. Had to use php curl file create to make it work instead of appending with '@'

http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-file-create.php

Answer (score 4):

Try to give full path of image instead of `'@/path/to/images/milk.jpg';`

Here is Updated code :

```
$token = '123456789';
$imgUrl = 'https://mytestapi.com/1.0/uploadimages';


$data_to_post = array();
$data_to_post['whitespace'] = '1';
$data_to_post['imageData'][] = "@".$imgUrl.'/path/to/images/milk.jpg';
$data_to_post['imageData'][] = "@".$imgUrl.'/path/to/images/peas.jpg';


$curl = curl_init($imgUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer '.$token]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_to_post);
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
$responseCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($data);
```

Please let me know if this not work.

Comment: did not work with full path. Anyway $imgUrl is the API URL so your code appending that to image file name does not make sense?  Anyway I was able to fix it just now using  php curl file create

Answer (score 0):

How to Upload a File using PHP cURL

```
<?php 

// Helper function courtesy of https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/3a0787217e6c0246b457e637ddd33332efea1d2a/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/PostFile.php#L90
function getCurlValue($filename, $contentType, $postname)
{
    // PHP 5.5 introduced a CurlFile object that deprecates the old @filename syntax
    // See: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
        return curl_file_create($filename, $contentType, $postname);
    }

    // Use the old style if using an older version of PHP
    $value = "@{$this->filename};filename=" . $postname;
    if ($contentType) {
        $value .= ';type=' . $contentType;
    }

    return $value;
}

$filename = '/path/to/file.jpg';
$cfile = getCurlValue($filename,'image/jpeg','cattle-01.jpg');

//NOTE: The top level key in the array is important, as some apis will insist that it is 'file'.
$data = array('file' => $cfile);

$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'http://your/server/api/upload',
             CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
             CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true, //Request header
             CURLOPT_HEADER => true, //Return header
             CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, //Don't veryify server certificate
             CURLOPT_POST => true,
             CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
            );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$header_info = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($result, $header_size);
curl_close($ch);

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>File Upload results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Raw Result: <?=$result?>
    <p>Header Sent: <?=$header_info?></p>
    <p>Header Received: <?=$header?></p>
    <p>Body: <?=$body?></p>
</body>
</html>
```